# Why the blue component of the moonlight is less scattered in Earth's atmosphere than the sunlight?

Tags: visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science, sun, moon

Why the blue component of the moonlight is less scattered in Earth's atmosphere than the sunlight? So when rising one of them looks yellow and the other red. Is this only matter of their brightness ratio and if so would then a brighter Sun look redish through Earth's atmosphere a lot before sunset?

Comment: There are some good answers here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14102/why-cant-moon-light-reflected-sun-light-turn-the-sky-blue/14103

Comment: The angle of incidence matters here.  When scattered orthogonal to the angle of incidence, the photons experience a blue shift.  When scattered parallel, the photons experience a red shift.  Pollution and particulates in the air also help to change the colors during sunrise and sunset.